# java event that run every hour or so after the application is launched

Tags: java, mysql, events

I am working on an application in Java that tell you if one of the document are overdue from database.
I tried event handler but did not figure it out.
How to make an event that do so every hour?

```
table = new JTable();
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        try
        {
            int row=table.getSelectedRow();
            String id=(table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
            String query="select * from employes where id='"+id+"'";
            PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();


            while(rs.next())
            {
                jtfid.setText(rs.getString("id"));
                jtfcni.setText(rs.getString("cni"));
                jtfnom.setText(rs.getString("nom"));
                jtfprenom.setText(rs.getString("prenom"));
                jtftele.setText(rs.getString("tel"));
                jtfaffectation.setText(rs.getString("affectation"));
                jtfxp.setText(rs.getString("xperience"));
                date.setText(rs.getString("date_de_embauche"));
            }
```

Comment: Lunched ? Is this run at 12:00 each day ? ;-)

Comment: Improved code format and grammar.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define jobs to run this code, you can use Quartz (https://quartz-scheduler.org/)